# Heater cartridge connector for Original Prusa i3 MK2S

Tags: prusa-i3, electronics, prusa-i3-rework, wire-type

I am thinking about rewiring the extruder heater cartridge. What is the connector on the Rambo Mini? I'm thinking about putting a similar connector close to the extruder to make replacement easy. I tried looking through [the schematic](https://github.com/ultimachine/Mini-Rambo/blob/1.3a/board/Project%20Outputs%20for%20Mini-Rambo/Mini-Rambo.PDF) but could find the part number for the connector (I believe on page 4?).

[image]

Comment: I removed the first question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is referred to as a Terminal Block Connector.   More specifically this is a 2-position pluggable terminal block connector commonly manufactured by Phoenix Contact and others.

[Newark.com Sale Page: Pluggable Terminal Block, 5.08 mm, 2 Positions, 24 AWG, 12 AWG, 2.5 mm², Screw](http://www.newark.com/phoenix-contact/1757019/terminal-block-pluggable-2-position/dp/71C4152)

[Larger Picture: 2-Position Terminal Block Connectors](https://images.monoprice.com/productlargeimages/121313.jpg)